# How to restrict to numeric digits except 0 after decimal point

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to restrict the numeric digits after the decimal point and allow only digit zero. For example if the value is 3431.0000 then this value is valid. However, If it the value is 3431.1110 or 3431.1000 then it is invalid. Can any one please help me on how I can add the rules to restrict for such requirement in my schema file?  I am using JAXB validator for validating the schemas and below is the code snippet from my schema file.

```
<xs:simpleType name="Decimal8-2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="4" />
        <xs:minExclusive value="0" />
        <xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{4}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Be aware that when you use a pattern facet to restrict the lexical space of a numeric type, you're making life very difficult for any application that has to generate this XML format. My advice would be that the schema should always permit alternative lexical representations that map to the same underlying value. But of course if you're trying to constrain the data to fit with the demands of an existing application, this might not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close.  Just change

```
  <xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{4}" />
```

to

```
  <xs:pattern value="\d+\.0{4}" />
```

in order to require that all of the fraction digits be `0`.

Comment: Awesome brother it worked! Thanks a lot for pointing it to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xs:pattern value="\d+\.0{4}" />
```

The other answer is correct, but it will accept all kind of digits in unicode, to be sure that it will only accept Western Arabic Number (1,2,..etc) I would avoid the use of "/d" in xsd-regex and use [0-9] instead like

```
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]+\.0{4}" />
```

Regex parser in xsd accept number like (١,٢,٣,٤,..etc) as a valid digit. Mostly it is not what you want

Also using [0-9] comes handy if you want to avoid leading zero like 092 so you can write your regex as:

```
<xs:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]*\.0{4}" />
```